# Prove that $\{w \mid \text{ w has even length and the first half of w has more 0s than the second half of w} \}$ is not regular?

Tags: proof-writing, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I have had some difficulties understanding proofs that a language is not regular using the Pumping Lemma, and now I need to prove that the following language

$$A = \{w \mid \text{ w has even length and the first half of w has more 0s than the second half of w} \}$$

is not regular.

I would start by assuming that $A$ is regular, and then I should pick a string in $A$ that for a certain $p$ (pumping length) would contradict the assumptions, i.e. $A$ is regular.

I think I first need to choose a string $s$, which of course must have ***even** length*, and the first part of that string must contain more $0$s than the second part. For example, $0001$ would be a string in $A$.

The length of $s$ must be greater or equal to $p$. Moreover, $s$ can be divided into three pieces, like $s = xyz$.

Now, how would I choose $s$? I saw that some proofs make $s$ depend on $p$. Is this strictly necessary, or is this just convenient, and why?

Could you please help me proceeding with the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining $s$ partly in terms of $p$ is an easy way to ensure that $|s|\ge p$; this is necessary if we are to apply the pumping lemma. It also gives us some control over what the part $xy$ of the $xyz$ decomposition will look like.

Here I would start with an $s$ that just barely satisfies the condition putting it in $A$: $s=0^p10^{p-1}$. If $A$ were regular, there would be a decomposition $s=xyz$ such that $|xy|\le p$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^kz\in A$ for each $k\ge 0$. Since $|xy|\le p$, we know that $xy$ is a string of zeroes: it’s part of the initial substring $0^p$ of $s$. Thus, there are $i,j$ such that $x=0^i$, $y=0^j$, $i+j\le p$, $i\ge 0$, and $j\ge 1$. (We know that $j\ge 1$, because $j=|y|\ge 1$.) This means that $z=0^{p-(i+j)}10^{p-1}$, and our decomposition is

$$s=x\color{red}y\color{blue}z=0^i\color{red}{0^j}\color{blue}{0^{p-(i+j)}10^{p-1}}\;.$$

Now what does $xy^kz$ look like for $k\ge 0$? It’s

$$xy^kz=0^i(0^j)^k0^{p-(i+j)}10^{p-1}=0^{i+kj+p-i-j}10^{p-1}=0^{p+(k-1)j}10^{p-1}\;.$$

In particular, when $k=0$ it’s $xz=0^{p-j}10^{p-1}$, where $j\ge 1$. Can you see why this word **cannot** be in $A$?

Comment: @nbro: Part of it is experience: I know what sorts of things to look for. Here I see that $A$ requires the first half of the word to have lots of zeroes, and I know that the pumping lemma will let me alter the first half of the word, so my first thought is to try to use it to make the number of zeroes in the first half too small. This will be easiest if the number of zeroes in the first half is only just barely large enough, so I started with a word in which that was the case. (Beginners often forget about the $k=0$ case, which lets you shrink the front end of the word.)

Comment: @nbro: True, though that just means that if $A$ *were* regular, there would always be an acceptable decomposition with $j$ even. Thus, you can’t count on destroying the evenness of the length, but you *can* count on making the first half of the word have too few zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can language can be proven not regular using the pumping lemma. The strongest statement of the pumping lemma will work: if $L$ is regular, then there is a $p$ (equal to the number of states in a DFA accepting $L$), such that for any string $s\in L$, *any* substring $r$ of $s$ of length $\ge p$ has substrings that can be pumped. The proof is the same: given any substring $r$ of $s$ with $\lvert r\rvert\ge p$, the states that the DFA must traverse when "processing" $r$ are $p+1$ in number, so there must be repetition.)

If the $L$ in question were regular, let $p$ be the length given by the pumping lemma, and consider $s=0^{p+1}1^p$. Then $s\in L$. But some substring of the $1$s can be pumped, and the resulting strings will be in $L$. But clearly that's not true: the "pumped-up$ strings won't satisfy the definition of the language.