# Prove that language is not context free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

Could you give me any tip (not a solution) how to prove that the language of even length words over the alphabet $\{ 0, 1 \}$ such that the number of $1$ in the first half is equal or greater than the number of $1$ in the second half is not context free?

This task can be seen as the next part of the task from:    [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530683/prove-that-w-mid-text-w-has-even-length-and-the-first-half-of-w-has-more-0)

I tried to use pumping lemma for context free languages but its usage in this case seems to be highly non-trivial for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Once the pumping lemma gives you a pumping length $p$, ask it to slice up the word $\mathtt 0^p\mathtt 1^p\mathtt 0^p\mathtt 1^p$.

For some of the slicings you'll have to pump *backwards* (that is, from one repetition to none).

Comment: Thanks, I've forgotten that you can unpump :)